# How join annotate value of QuerySet and property field of Model to one logic in Django?

Tags: django

I have this situation. I calculate a diameter in two ways: annotate of QuerySet and property in Model.

```py
class CircleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_diameter(self):
        return self.annotate(diameter=models.F('radius')*2)


class Circle(models.Model):
    radius = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)

    objects = CircleQuerySet.as_manager()

    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.radius * 2
```

How can I join this two ways to one? Is it exists?

Comment: What do you mean by joining them into one?

Comment: Something that is used in annotate and model. Write logic of calculating diameter in one place and use it everywhere.

Comment: For your example there should be no problem removing the annotation and having the logic in the property as it is a very simple calculation

Comment: How can I use queryset filter by diameter without annotate diameter? QuerySet does not see  model properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `setter` for the diameter property so that you do not get errors when trying to add an annotation of the same name

```
@property
def diameter(self):
    return self.radius * 2

@diameter.setter
def diameter(self, value):
    return
```

As for only having the calculation in one place, it is not possible because the annotation is a database instruction and you still need the property for objects that are not retrieved from the database. You could add the annotation to every query by overriding the `get_queryset` method of the manager so that even `.get()` will return an object with the annotation.